# debugging ex_bad_access with gdb in c++

Tags: macos, debugging, gdb, g++, exc-bad-access

I'm compiling code from the command line with g++ on Mac OSX and have an error when I run my code that results in an EXC_BAD_ACCESS

I've seen that the most helpful way to debug this kind of error is with Zombie objects that don't deallocate when released and then complain when code tries to release them.

However, it seems that NSZombie options are available in Xcode/Objective C.

So my question is there any way to use this functionality/equivalent in programs simply compiled code like

```
g++ file1.cpp -g -o executable
```

debugged with

```
gdb executable
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Zombie objects are a concept of Objective-C, not C++, and relate to reference counting issues, which C++ doesn't use (unless you count smart pointers and *Enabling Zombies* won't help you with that anyway).

So, to answer your question; No, there is no way to use that functionality.

If you want to find the issue then you'll need to use a debugger.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I am using a debugger (gdb) and know from that where the code is breaking, but I can't find out what has been overreleased as it doesn't exist anymore. Do you know how to use gdb for this?